# Autofocus camera does not focus in when in OpenCV Python Object Detection

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, raspberry-pi4

I have problems with my object detection using OpenCV in python perhaps because I cannot adjust the focus of my IMX519 Camera. Here is my code that I run on my Raspberry Pi 4B.

`

```
def Camera_start(wx,hx):
    global p
    rpistr = "libcamera-still -t 0 --segment 1 --afmode manual --manualfocus 500 --codec mjpeg -n -o /run/shm/test%06d.jpg --width " + str(wx) + " --height " + str(hx)
    p = subprocess.Popen(rpistr, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

`

Comment: libcamera-vid -t 20000 --autofocus -o myHDvideo.h264 --width 1920 --height 1080 That all I have.

Comment: rpistr = "libcamera-still    -t 0 --segment 1 --afmode manual --manualfocus 500 --codec mjpeg -n -o /run/shm/test%06d.jpg --width " + str(wx) + " --height " + str(hx)